# Xcode User Defaults unrecognized selector error

Tags: xcode, unrecognized-selector, defaults

I'm getting started to use User Defaults on Cocoa and I'm getting an [NSConcreteData alphaComponent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance `0x100123660` error. Here is the source code :

AppDelegate.m file :

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{
NSColor *myColor = [NSColor greenColor];
[PreferencesController setDefaultColor:myColor];
NSColor *color = (NSColor *)[PreferencesController defaultColor];
NSLog(@"Default color : %@ - %@",(NSColor *)color, [NSColor greenColor]);
[tableView setBackgroundColor:color];
[colorWell setColor:color];
}
```

PreferencesController.m file :

```
+ (NSColor *)defaultColor{
NSColor * aColor;
NSData *theData=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]      valueForKey:TableViewBackgroundColorKey];
if (theData != nil)
    aColor = (NSColor *)[NSUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:theData];
return aColor;
}

+ (void)setDefaultColor:(NSColor *)color{
NSData *theData=[NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:theData  forKey:TableViewBackgroundColorKey];
}
```

The return value of the NSLog is :

```
<040b7374 7265616d 74797065 6481e803 84014084 8484074e 53436f6c 6f720084 84084e53
4f626a65 63740085 84016301 84046666 66660001 000186> - NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1
```

So the value returned by `+ (NSColor *)defaultColor` is not an NSColor, and certainly not    `[NSColor greeenColor]`.

I'm also getting the error `-[NSConcreteData alphaComponent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100184050`, which I think must be caused by not returning an `NSColor` for the method mentioned.

Please help me to debug.

Thanks.

Comment: what is PreferencesController ?

Comment: How did you set the value for `MDCTableViewBgKey` in `NSUserDefaults` in the first place? You are unarchiving an NSData instead of an NSColor, so the problem probably comes from when you archived it and set it.

Comment: Well PreferencesController is my custom class of NSWindowController and MDCTableViewBgKey is set as an extern string : NSString * const MDCTableViewBgKey = @"TableViewBackgroundColor". But I don't get what you mean by saying "You are unarchiving an NSData instead of an NSColor".

Comment: The set method is :
`+ (void)setDefaultColor:(NSColor *)color{
NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver    archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:colorData forKey:MDCTableViewBgKey];
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to handle NSColor in a special way, when storing it in user defaults. NSColor is not an object that can be represented in an property list; see [Storing NSColor in User Defaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/StoringNSColorInDefaults.html) for code examples.

Comment: Using the link, I've got 2 new error : `Default color : (null)` (while it should be the white color) and `*** Assertion failure in -[NSColorWell setColor:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1187.34/AppKit.subproj/NSColorWell.m:500`. No idea what that means.

Comment: The code has become : `+ (NSColor *)defaultColor{
    NSColor * aColor =nil;
    NSData *theData=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dataForKey:MDCTableViewBgKey];
    if (theData != nil)
        aColor =(NSColor *)[NSUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:theData];
    return aColor;
}`

Comment: and
`+ (void)setDefaultColor:(NSColor *)color{
    /*NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:colorData forKey:MDCTableViewBgKey];*/
    NSData *theData=[NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:MDCTableViewBgKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:theData forKey:MDCTableViewBgKey];
};`

Comment: In your last comment, the argument for `archivedDataWithRootObject` shouldn't be the key, but the object: `NSData *theData=[NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];`

Comment: Okay but still, there is a little problem when it logs the color : I'm getting `<040b7374 7265616d 74797065 6481e803 84014084 8484074e 53436f6c 6f720084 84084e53 4f626a65 63740085 84016301 84046666 66660001 000186>` instead of `NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1` just after the line (added) `[PreferencesController setDefaultColor:[NSColor greenColor]]`. The first object is not an NSColor if I'm right. Why `+(NSColor *)defaultColor`doesn't return an NSColor?

Comment: Are sure, that setDefaultColor is correctly called? Do you have a setter method for defaultColor? Try `NSColor *myColor = [NSColor greenColor]; [PreferencesController setDefaultColor:myColor];`

Comment: Nope, nothing changed with your code. But I don't see the difference between.

Comment: Could you please update your post with the recent code. I lost the overview through the changes you made.

Comment: Sorry, you're right it was quite messed up. The code is updated. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Add to recap, the problem is that I'm getting `<040b7374 7265616d 74797065 6481e803 84014084 8484074e 53436f6c 6f720084 84084e53 4f626a65 63740085 84016301 84046666 66660001 000186> - NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1`for the log and not `NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1 - NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1` as it should be.

Comment: In `setDefaultColor` you are encapsulating the NSColor twice in this line: `NSData *theData=[NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color]];` - it should be `NSData *theData=[NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];`

Comment: Okay, this was actually the problem but when I delete the lines
`NSColor *myColor = [NSColor greenColor];
[PreferencesController setDefaultColor:myColor];`
to use the previous saved user default, I still get the same error.

Comment: ??? When you don't call anywhere `setDefaultColor` how should `defaultColor` return a valid result? If it's not set in the defaults, `defaultColor` will always return `nil`. You'll have to set the default value *somewhere* initially by calling `setDefaultColor` and you can then change it later. E.g. test in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` if the value is set and set it to default if not.

Comment: I'm calling `- setDefaultColor:(NSColor *)` in the `+ (void)initilize` method : `[PreferencesController setDefaultColor:[NSColor whiteColor]]`.

Comment: I don't think that this method (especially with this signature) ever get's called since the init of NIB is done transparently. Put the line into `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: a) Since I answered your original question and debugged it further, I would appreciate, when you accept my answer.

Comment: b) *What* exactly doesn't work? You changed greenColor with whiteColor  and it stopped working? Can't be.

Comment: I've just deleted the lines `NSColor *myColor = [NSColor greenColor];
[PreferencesController setDefaultColor:myColor];` to use the setter defaults.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't move this thread to a chat, since your rep is too low... Copy your complete code to a [gist](https://gist.github.com), post the link and I'll have another look.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://gist.github.com/f3f91aba81f6e7003b11). But the code in the gist is the whole code of the app. The only problem is the part dealing with user defaults.

Comment: I commented on the gist page. Let's move to that; this is not the right place to chat.